# OpenStack Dashboard (Horizon) Fails to Allow Log In

Tags: ubuntu, openstack

I cannot log in to the OpenStack Dashboard; attempting to do so results in a re-direct back to the log-in page.

Entering the wrong details will throw an "incorrect user/pass" error; the correct details will show nothing.

I cannot see any issues in `/var/log/nova-api.log` or similar.

My `apache2/error.log` does show some 401's relating to Cinder, but I'm not sure if these are a red herring: https://gist.github.com/elithrar/15913c5196c744777083

`nova-manage service list` shows smiley faces, and `keystone service-list` shows the expected services with no errors.

I'd appreciate some advice here—a Google hasn't helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those unauthorized errors in the error log might be the problem.  A start would be to validate that the user you are logging into Horizon with has (in keystone) the role that you've specified in the /etc/openstack-dashboard/local_settings.py ( OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_DEFAULT_ROLE = "some role name" )

Comment: Thanks; there was an error w/ Cinder using the incorrect credentials. 401's were resulting in Horizon automatically logging me out upon a successful login. 

Note that this behaviour is changed in Grizzly, for the benefit of other readers: https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/ReleaseNotes/Grizzly#.E2.80.9CNot_Authorized.E2.80.9D_.26_Being_Logged_Out